# MYSQL WPDataCharts Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have very little knowledge of MYSQL so please forgive me. I have a wordpress form using Formidable Forms. I am querying the database to find forms that were logged from the beginning of this month to the current date which is....

```
SELECT month(created_at) as Month, count(id) as Tickets
FROM wp_frm_item_metas
WHERE date(created_at) < now() and date(created_at) > last_day(curdate()  - interval 1 month) and field_id=30
```

field_id=30 is the date field. This procedure works.

I also have a similar procedure for last month which gives me the forms created from the beginning of last month to the same date of last month so if today is 14/08. The procedure would display a count of all forms from 01/07-14/07 which it does...

```
SELECT month(created_at) as Month, count(id) as Tickets
FROM wp_frm_item_metas
WHERE date(created_at) < NOW () - interval 1 month and date(created_at) >  last_day(curdate() - interval 2 month) and field_id=30;
```

I need to try to join these so they output the data in the same query. Is this possible? I've tried union and join and everything tells me I have an error in my code. The error that comes up is cannot calculate position of the second select.

I would also like it to calculate the number of days left in the current month and I will be adding another procedure to give me the total forms created last month so I can run formulas on them.

So the table will look like...

Month     Tickets
08        60
07        89
Total LM  194
Diff      134
Days Left 17
Target    7.8

Apologies for the long question and I appreciate any help.

Thanks

So I have the right data now but I need to change the order it appears. My query is...

`(SELECT month(created_at) as Month, count(id) as Tickets
FROM wp_frm_item_metas
WHERE date(created_at) < now() and date(created_at) > last_day(curdate()  - interval 1 month) and field_id=30)
UNION
(SELECT month(created_at) as Month, count(id) as Tickets
FROM wp_frm_item_metas
WHERE date(created_at) < NOW () - interval 1 month and date(created_at) >  last_day(curdate() - interval 2 month) and field_id=30)
UNION
(SELECT month(created_at) as Month, count(id) as Tickets
FROM wp_frm_item_metas
WHERE date(created_at) <= last_day(now() - interval 1 month) and date(created_at) > last_day(now() - interval 2 month) and field_id=30)
UNION
(SELECT DAYOFMONTH(now()) as D1, DAY(LAST_DAY(now())) as DaysInMonth);`

This gives me the table...

`Month.....Tickets
8.....62
7.....84
7.....194
14....31`

The first row is the forms created this month. 84 is the forms created to the same date last month. 194 is the total for last month and the last row is the day of the month and the total days in the month.

I need to change the format slighly so I can do calculations on the results.

I need...

`ThisMth.....LastMth.....LastMthTotal
62..........84..........194
14..........31`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UNION is the correct answer, if you want both as rows

But you need to enter around both SELECTS parenthesis

```
(SELECT month(created_at) as Month, count(id) as Tickets
FROM wp_frm_item_metas
WHERE date(created_at) < now() and date(created_at) > last_day(curdate()  - interval 1 month) and field_id=30)
UNION
(SELECT month(created_at) as Month, count(id) as Tickets
FROM wp_frm_item_metas
WHERE date(created_at) < NOW () - interval 1 month and date(created_at) >  last_day(curdate() - interval 2 month) and field_id=30);
```

for that you can use

```
(SELECT (SELECT month(created_at) as Month, count(id) as Tickets
FROM wp_frm_item_metas
WHERE date(created_at) < now() and date(created_at) > last_day(curdate()  - interval 1 month) and field_id=30) ThisMth
,
(SELECT month(created_at) as Month, count(id) as Tickets
FROM wp_frm_item_metas
WHERE date(created_at) < NOW () - interval 1 month and date(created_at) >  last_day(curdate() - interval 2 month) and field_id=30) LastMth
,
(SELECT month(created_at) as Month, count(id) as Tickets
FROM wp_frm_item_metas
WHERE date(created_at) <= last_day(now() - interval 1 month) and date(created_at) > last_day(now() - interval 2 month) and field_id=30) LastMthTotal)
UNION
(SELECT DAYOFMONTH(now()) as D1, DAY(LAST_DAY(now())) as DaysInMonth,'');
```

Comment: That worked great. Thank you. Just need to work out how to calculate number of days left in the month now.

Comment: I've edited my question to show what I mean. I have all the data but need it rearranged.

Comment: try the changed answer

Comment: Tried the new answer. I get... No data fetched!
MySQL said: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: then i am  sorry, you have to show a data example, that leads to oyur erro meassge im a dbfiddle.